# combining data from two tables in a database to get total sum (C#)

Tags: c#, sql, .net, database

I'm new to databases, and I need help. I have a database with two tables ([tb_TotalH], [tb_PricePerH]). The first table [tb_TotalH] shows the total number of hours per day, and in the second table [tb_PricePerH] are the prices of the hour with the date they were created.
[image]

I need to calculate the total amount (hours per day multiply price per hour).
But the trick is that the price of the hour is not fixed, it changes and I need a price in the period when working hours were made. And I also need to get the price when I make query for filter of dates to get the price in label. 
**I have no idea how to start this!**
This is some of my code that I've done so far:

```
     SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True");

    void DisplayData()
    {

        con.Open();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from tb_TotalH", con);
        sda.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        con.Close();

        dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns();
    }


    void BetweenDates()
    {
        DateTime dtFrom = Convert.ToDateTime(dtp1.Value);
        DateTime dtTo = Convert.ToDateTime(dtp2.Value);
        SqlDataAdapter mda = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from DailyDataEntry where Date_H between '" + dtFrom.ToShortDateString() + "' and '" + dtTo.ToShortDateString() + "' ", con);



        System.Data.DataSet ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
        con.Open();
        mda.Fill(ds, "root");
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["root"];
        dataGridView1.Refresh();
        con.Close();
    }

    void getPrice()
    {
        SqlDataReader rdr = null;
        SqlCommand cmd = null;

        con.Open();


        string CommandText = "SELECT Price, Tax FROM tb_PricePerH WHERE Date_M = @date"; 
        cmd = new SqlCommand(CommandText);
        cmd.Connection = con;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", "4/22/2018");  

        rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            lbl1.Text = Convert.ToDouble(rdr["PricePerHour"].ToString());
            lbl2.Text = Convert.ToDouble(rdr["Tax"].ToString());
        }


        con.Close();
    }
```

Comment: could you show sample output ?

Comment: It appears that no one can work over midnight, so the problem becomes one of finding the applicable hourly rate for a given date. Is the intent that the hourly rate is the one for: (1) the date in question, if it exists, or (B) the latest priced date prior to the date in question? Since you haven't explained _how_ to calculate the total sum it's a bit of a challenge for us to help you. Aside: You convert numeric values to strings to doubles to strings for display in labels? Tip: Reasons not to use images are [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/92546).

Comment: @HABO If you do not want to help you do not have to, and the question was not for that strings,doubles,strings, code is in the test phase. And any help  even if is not in code is welcome, and if I had experience, I would not ask the question here.

Comment: @Anu Viswan For example, on 07.05.2018 the total hours for this day was 9h, in that period (from tb_PricePerH) the price of the hour was 11, because it started 06.19.2018. So on this day the profit was 99.

Comment: You may find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42585072/92546) answer to be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to mock your scenario with List.

```
var tablePricePerHours = new List<TablePricePerHours>
    {
        new TablePricePerHours{ Price = 10, Tax = 19, Date = new DateTime(2018,1,5)},
        new TablePricePerHours{ Price = 10.5, Tax = 21.5, Date = new DateTime(2018,4,22)},
        new TablePricePerHours{ Price = 11, Tax = 22.5, Date = new DateTime(2018,6,19)},
        new TablePricePerHours{ Price = 11.5, Tax = 23, Date = new DateTime(2018,10,30)},
        new TablePricePerHours{ Price = 12, Tax = 23.2, Date = new DateTime(2018,11,1)}
    };

    var tableTotalHours = new List<TableTotalHours>
    {
        new TableTotalHours{ Date = new DateTime(2018,02,15), TotalHours = 5},
        new TableTotalHours{ Date = new DateTime(2018,02,19), TotalHours =10},
        new TableTotalHours{ Date = new DateTime(2018,02,25), TotalHours = 8},
        new TableTotalHours{ Date = new DateTime(2018,03,29), TotalHours = 7.5},
        new TableTotalHours{ Date = new DateTime(2018,07,05), TotalHours = 9},
        new TableTotalHours{ Date = new DateTime(2018,07,06), TotalHours = 1.5},
        new TableTotalHours{ Date = new DateTime(2018,07,07), TotalHours = 12},
        new TableTotalHours{ Date = new DateTime(2018,10,22), TotalHours = 10},
        new TableTotalHours{ Date = new DateTime(2018,10,22), TotalHours = 10},
        new TableTotalHours{ Date = new DateTime(2018,11,1), TotalHours = 8},
        new TableTotalHours{ Date = new DateTime(2018,12,21), TotalHours = 8.5},
        new TableTotalHours{ Date = new DateTime(2018,12,22), TotalHours = 9},
    };
```

Where TablePricePerHours and TableTotalHours are defined as

```
public class TableTotalHours
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public DateTime Date{get;set;}
    public double TotalHours{get;set;}
}


public class TablePricePerHours
{
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public double Price{get;set;}
    public double Tax{get;set;}
    public DateTime Date{get;set;}
}
```

Now you can get the required result with Linq as

```
var result = tableTotalHours.Select(x=> new 
                                    {
                                        Date=x.Date,
                                        TotalHours=x.TotalHours,
                                        CalculatedPrice = tablePricePerHours.Where(c=> (x.Date - c.Date).Ticks>0)
                                                                            .OrderBy(c=> (x.Date - c.Date).Ticks)
                                                                            .First()
                                                                            .Price * x.TotalHours
                                    });
```

**Output**

[image]

You can find the same [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lF925a)

Comment: YES! :) 1074.50 is a correct number!  Thank you very much for the answer, I am glad that there are still people who want to help inexperienced programmers! But tell me should I also transfer my tables to List??  and can you please write this "result = tableTotalHours.Select(x=>" on normal c# and not on Linq, so I can understand better.